# Убрать index.html с главной

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, редирект, http-status-code-301

На сайте появились дубли страниц - самописный сайт.
Мне нужно убрать с главной  index.html т.к робот индексирует их как две и зайти на них можно по разному

```
  http://www.dom.startnet.info/index.html

   http://www.dom.startnet.info/
```

хотя это одна страница.
Что я не писал в .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://www.имя сайта.ru/ [R=301,L]
```

и

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [QSA,R]
```

и еще кучу примеров перебрал index.html не уходит.
Одна зацепка когда я вместо html прописал php в

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.имя сайта.com/ [R=301,L]
```

и поменял на всех других страницах переход кроме самой главной на index.php  стала появляться чистое `http://www.dom.startnet.info/`  но как только я изменил главную `http://www.dom.startnet.info/index.html` на  `http://www.dom.startnet.info/index.php`  стала главная error403
Мужыки помогите долбусь уже два дня перепробовал все варианты с интернета - чувствую мелочь гдето зарыта а найти не могу.

Comment: У вас сервер называется `nginx`, а не `Apache`.

Answer (score 1):

Для запрета индексации index.html  и index.php стоит создать файл `robots.txt` в корне сайта с таким содержимым

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /index.html
Disallow: /index.php
```

**UPD: 
 Готовый c редеректом index.html и php**

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteEngine On

# Index file
DirectoryIndex index.html 

# Redirects
 RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [QSA,R]
 RewriteRule ^index.html$ / [QSA,R]

# Error files
ErrorDocument 401 /error/401.php 
ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.php 
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php 
ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.php
```

Если у вас Nginx то соответственно это в конфигурацию:

```
index index.html;
charset utf-8;
error_page 500 /error/500.php;
error_page 404 /error/404.php;
error_page 403 /error/403.php;
location /index {
  rewrite ^/index.php$ / redirect;
  rewrite ^/index.html$ / redirect; 
}
```

Comment: спасибо попробую

Comment: Все равно вставляеш http://www.dom.startnet.info/index.html он не переходит на http://www.dom.startnet.info  а заходит на нее но http://www.dom.startnet.info/index.html

Comment: Вы описали проблему в том что бот индексирует страницу как копию, но с помощью способа выше можно ему это запретить, т.е все будет также только бот не будет индексировать эти страницы

Comment: а сам бот исправить нельзя?  Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что значит "сам бот" ?

Comment: Начну с начала:

Comment: Есть сайт http://www.dom.startnet.info/    если я допишу в конце index.php и нажму enter то загрузится http://www.dom.startnet.info/    если я допишу в конце index.html то загрузится http://www.dom.startnet.info/index.html . Мне нужно чтоб загрузилась без    index.html. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Попробуйте так `Redirect 301 /index.html http://вашсайт.ru/`

Comment: Перестает грузиться главная вообще у меня сейчас                                                  AddDefaultCharset UTF-8  
RewriteEngine On          

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dom\.startnet\.info$ [NC]      
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dom.startnet.info/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html\ HTTP/      
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ http://www.dom.startnet.info/ [R=301,L]       
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/      
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.dom.startnet.info/ [R=301,L]      

DirectoryIndex index.html       
ErrorDocument 401 /error/401.php      
ErrorDocument 403 /error/403.php      
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.php      
ErrorDocument 500 /error/500.php

Comment: Это весь ваш htaccess?

Comment: да больше ничего нет - пока

Comment: Я взял ваш .htaccess и навёл в нем порядок, и прописал редиректы, и протестировал, добавил в ответ выше

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!!!!

Comment: Просто нажмите галочку возле ответа она под низом стрелки показывающей в низ